# Error in python-igraph 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'

Tags: python, import, pycharm, igraph

I have installed igraph on Pycharm for Windows.

```
import igraph
```

yields no errors.

```
import igraph
print igraph.__version__
```

yields: 0.1.5.

```
import igraph
dir(igraph)
```

yields nothing...

```
import igraph
g = igraph.Graph(1)
```

yields:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Margaret/PycharmProjects/untitled/trial.py", line 2, in
>   
>       g = igraph.Graph(1)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'

Does anyone know what the issue might be? I've looked at all the previously asked questions I could find and I haven't found an answer that will work for my case. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about the version history of `igraph`, but with 0.7.1, your code works as you expected.  Is it possible to update?

Comment: So the installation didn't go well... to me `dir(igraph)` returns a bunch of stuff.

Comment: Did you install it by running: `pip install python-igraph` ? or `pip install igraph` ? you should use the former! in case you ran the latter, it will seem to be installed but it's messed up...

Comment: Are those examples meant to be in the console? If not, you need to `print dir(igraph)`.

Comment: @alfasin That's it exactly. There are two different packages. `pip install python-igraph`

Comment: @PeterWood yes, I suspect that the OP installed the wrong one.

Comment: Upon running print dir(igraph) as @PeterWood said, I was able to get output. You all are right about the mistaken installation of the wrong igraph package. However I run into more problems with that as described below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two `igraph` libraries on PyPI, [`igraph`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/igraph) and [`python-igraph`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-igraph).

You have `igraph` installed, which is the wrong one. Uninstall it using:

```
pip uninstall igraph
```

As you are on Windows you probably need a pre-compiled distribution, called a wheel.

[This site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) has lots of wheels which can be installed using `pip`. Here is [the wheel for `python-igraph`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-igraph).

Install using, e.g.:

```
pip install python_igraph-0.7.1.post4-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

Comment: I have tried doing this, and upon installing it I get an error that says "An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket". I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong though... I have been using Pycharm to run python codes, but I'm assuming I need to be running the 'pip install ... ' from the command prompt? Can you tell me more specifically how I do this correctly?

Comment: @MargaretMcDaniel That's another question for another time. I would follow the normal instructions for `pip`. I know PyCharm can install without `pip` being installed in your basic Python installation, so it's possible it won't work from the command line until you install pip separately. You can do that though, it won't affect PyCharm.